# How can I assign an image to an input element?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, input

I'm writing an ASP-MVC application in C#. I have an `input` element of type `submit` and I want it to display an image. Here is the declaration of my button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

How can I display an image on that button?

Comment: Did you try CSS? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: -1: The wording is unclear, especially with all the redundant punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<input type="image" src="/images/mypic.gif" />
```

Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: my input type is submit for that i want to provide the image please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: If you need a image then you use the image type, that will act the same way as a submit type do.

OR you use <button><img src=".." alt=""/> </button> but I would suggest the first option